# Couldn't load provisioning profile from data

Tags: xcode

I have a problem with provisioning profile. I downloaded it from apple developer.

But xcode says :

```
Couldn't load provisioning profile from data.
```

Previously it was working but now I don't know. Maybe clean my Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Try not downloading the provisioning profiles as a zip file, I had the same issue, however after downloading the files individually its worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the provisioning profile with textedit, if you see '**This attachment was removed because it contains data that could pose a security risk.**' then your mobileprovision file was actually a text file, this explains why it wasn't imported.

Try deleting all instances of provisioning profile(s) and download afresh, it should help you in resolving.